# Woocommerce Integration Settings API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, integration

I'm not really sure whether this needs to go in WooCommerce, Wordpress or PHP questions, I also don't really know what to call it as I have no idea what is going wrong, but hopefully one of you braniacs can help me here.

I'm doing a WooCommerce integration. Here is my code (stripped down for readability):

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_My_Integration' ) ) :

    class WC_My_Integration extends WC_Integration {

    public function __construct() {

        global $woocommerce;

        $this->id = 'my_id';
        $this->method_title       = __( 'My Title', 'my-text-domain' );

        $this->test_select = $this->get_option('test_select');

        $this->init_form_fields();

        add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_integration', array( &$this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
        // If I don't do this the changes aren't showing immediately
        $this->process_admin_options();
        var_dump($this->test_select);  // Returns correct result on save, but then disappears after page reload 
    }

    public function init_form_fields() {
        $this->form_fields = array(
            'test_select'   => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Test Select', 'my-text-domain' ),
                'type'        => 'select',
                'options'     => array(
                    'yes' => 'Yes',
                    'no'  => 'No'
                )
            ),
        );
    }

    public function test_function() {
        if('yes' === $this->test_select) {
            echo "Yes";
        } else {
            echo "No";
        }
    }

    public function process_admin_options() {    
        parent::process_admin_options();

        $this->test_select = get_option('test_select');
    }

    public function admin_options() {
        parent::admin_options();

    }
}
endif;
```

The problem is when I change the select option to yes / no, the change only reflects after I reload the page.

So, in other words, let's say the select option is set to "yes". I change it to "no", click the save button and the page reloads. The form shows that "no" is selected now, and the value of the var_dump() is "string 'no' (length=2)". The expected output of text_function() should now be "no". However, it still shows "yes".

Then, when I refresh the page the result of test_function() is correct and it echoes "no", but only after I refresh the page. Can anyone shed some light on this matter please?

I'm initializing the plugin correctly in my plugin file. Don't know if I need to include that as well?

**Update:**

I've updated the code above to reflect my changes after Magnavode's answer. Problem now is that the values are correct after save, but then disappear after page reload.

Comment: This is driving me insane. I've checked the database and the changes immediately reflect there. So where is the _construct function getting the data from? 

Any "get_option()" I put within the _construct function returns the old values and only show the new ones once I refresh the page.

Any "get_option()" I put inside the "admin_options()" function immediately shows the correct / expected result on save.

Anybody? Please help me keep what's left of my sanity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this is not the way to do it, but I'm left with no choice until someone can shed some further light on this.

I ended up adding the following to the admin_options() function:

```
if($this->test_select !== $this->get_option('test_select')) {
    header("Refresh:0");
}
```

This forces the page to reload if the two (exact same!!!) variables don't match. Obviously it will need to check all the options, but that is the basic idea.

Comment: A better solution is to rather do header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); than header("Refresh:0");. This way the refresh isn't noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

The bug you're having is because at the time your contructor is called process_admin_options() hasn't been called yet and so the posted form has not been saved to the database yet. Causing get_option to retreive the old value.

You can fix it by setting the class variables again after processing the post data. Overwrite process_admin_options like so:

```
public function process_admin_options() {
    parent::process_admin_options();

    $this->test_select = $this->get_option('test_select');
}
```

Or by dropping the class variables altogether and just calling `get_option` each time instead.

Also you should overwrite init_form_fields() and init your form fields from there.

Also your admin_options() is hiding the parent's admin_options().
Use this instead:

```
public function admin_options() {
    parent::admin_options();

    var_dump($this->test_select);
    var_dump($this->get_option('test_select'));
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for three days straight! Thanks. I added the process_admin_options() function you suggested and called that in my class and changed the admin_options() function to your suggestion. Works now! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Nope. I spoke too soon. The value does change on save, but as soon as you navigate away from the page or refresh it the values are discarded and the variables are empty... :-/

Comment: process_admin_options should only be called if there's actual post data to be processed. Remove the line and reset the value by clicking save changes.

Comment: Also use `add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_integration_' .  $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );` so you don't get the same problem when you multiple integration plugins.

Comment: Hi. Thanks alot for trying to help. Like I said in the code above. If I remove $this->process_admin_options from the constructor then I'm back to the old behaviour, which is what I'm trying to fix. If I add the line, then it saves but gets cleared on page refresh so either way I'm still not getting accepted results.

Comment: Also if I do add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_integration_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) ); the data does not get saved at all. That's why I omitted the $this->id. I've decided to just start over and go a different route. This all just seems way to buggy for any production site. I've checked a plethora of WooCommerce integration plugins and every single one has the same behaviour (not saving immediately). So it's not my code.

Answer (score 1):

My goal was to show/hide some settings depending on value of another. Since by default `init_form_fields()` is called before `process_admin_options()`, the show/hide wasn't work right after saving settings, but after settings page is reloded. I've achieved the goal by overriding `process_admin_options()`:

```php
public function process_admin_options() {

    $saved = parent::process_admin_options();
    $this->init_form_fields();
    return $saved;

}
```

and adding `init_settings()` call to `init_form_fields()`:

```php
public function init_form_fields() {

    $this->init_settings();
    $this->form_fields = [];

    if ( ! empty( $this->settings['one'] ) ) {
        // build a depending settings
    }

}
```